# Diverging Integral with Bessel Function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, bessel-functions, parameter-estimation

I am looking for the solution to the integral:

$$\int_{a}^{\infty} x J_n(\alpha x)\;dx$$

where $a<< \alpha$ and $n$. I get something out of Mathematica for $a=1,2,0.1...$ in terms of the Hypergeometric function. It makes me think that some conditional expression for the solution exists, I just fail to find it.

---

The original integral of interest is actually this one

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} x J_n(\alpha x)\;dx$$

However, I know, this one does not converge. Maybe someone knows how to estimate it at least in certain limits (n should be any)... I need to extract something sensible, not just "you failed, go on with your life" kind of a situation...

I have tried to truncate it on top and take a limit to infinity, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: You sure that's not a product of two Bessel functions? Because there's an orthogonality relation $\int_0^{\infty}xJ_n(\alpha x)J_n(\beta x)\,dx=0$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$. The sensible thing to extract may well be that we should have been working with a different integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original integral is the Hankel Transform of order n of the function $f(x) = 1$.

The Hankel Transform of order n, and its inverse, can be defined as

$$\mathscr{H}_n\left\{f(r)\right\} = F(q) = \int_0^\infty f(r)J_n(qr)r\space dr$$
$$\mathscr{H}^{-1}_n\left\{F(q)\right\} = f(r) = \int_0^\infty F(q)J_n(qr)q\space dq$$

Note that the Hankel Transform is its own inverse.

For $n = 0$, and for an appropriate definition of the Dirac Delta distribution, it is easy to show the answer to your integral by using the inverse transform:

$$\mathscr{H}^{-1}_0\left\{\dfrac{\delta(q)}{q}\right\} = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\delta(q)}{q}J_0(qr)q\space dq = 1$$
$$\mathscr{H}_0\left\{1\right\} = \int_0^\infty J_0(qr)r\space dr = \dfrac{\delta(q)}{q}$$

For higher orders of $n$, try to find a table of Hankel Transforms from a reliable source.